# NSDate from string problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsdateformatter

I surfed through existant questions regarding this theme, but my issue is little specific and i can't figure out source of the problem.

I have string like:

```
str = @"Sun Mar 06 13:20:12 2011";
```

And i want to convert it to NSTimeInterval. Im doing it this way:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"ddd mmm dd hh:mm:ss yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:str];

NSTimeInterval interval = [date timeIntervalSince1970];
```

"date" always gets nil.

I think I'm wrongly defining the format, but can't figure out at what part.

Comment: just as a tip, if you experience string-to-date problems you can get a hint what went wrong when you do the opposite and print it to the console. `NSLog(@"Date: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);` shows you quickly that there must be something wrong with the format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on http://www.deanoj.co.uk/ios-development/nsdateformatter-formatting-strings-reference/

you should use `ccc MMM dd hh:mm:ss yyyy` instead of `ddd mmm dd hh:mm:ss yyyy`

Comment: Fantastic site. And your answer is correct except of there is a need to change hh to HH in addition to ccc. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps

[NSDateFormatter dateFromString returns nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258266/nsdateformatter-datefromstring-returns-nil)

Comment: Yep. This helped. Had to change hh to HH in addition to changes provoded in previous answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I always advice you to avoid usage of nsdateformatter. Instead use nsdatecomponents. I have suffered a lot because of its instability. Intially it got fixed after using few properties of NSdateFormatter but I got the nil problem in 4.2.1 version of iOS.

chk this link to understand nsdateformatter better.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1480.html