# Error in NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am using the following line of code to create a dictionary which stores a url and the time when it was accessed::

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: urlString, [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]], nil];
```

But,however, I am getting the following error :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:]: second object of each pair must be non-nil.  Or, did you forget to nil-terminate your parameter list?'
```

Can someone help me to sort it out ?? I am stuck at this error. Thanks and regards.

Comment: It seems exceedingly odd -- wrong, even -- to use an arbitrary NSDate as a key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSDateFormatter` is probably returning `nil`. Check the return value, store it in a local variable, and add that variable to the dictionary instead.

```
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"dateString: %@", dateString); //will let you know if it's nil or not
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: urlString, dateString, nil];
```

You can check out why it might be returning `nil` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258266/nsdateformatter-datefromstring-returns-nil).

Comment: however if I write this one line just above the lines I wrote ::    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; then it is not nil !! :-/

Comment: Right on - then you know where to look! It's probably the format you're specifying. You look new around Stack Overflow, so generally what you do now is open a new question if you can't figure out why the `formatter` is returning `nil`. Good luck!