# NSDate String Not Showing In TableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7

I have installed the GM version of iOS 7, successfully upgraded everything needed to update my app to iOS 7 but there is one thing i am unable to troubleshoot related to NSDate. It was working fine with iOS 6 but in iOS 7 its not working.

In one file named TheItem.m, i am doing the following:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
            NSLog(@"TIMEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE %@", currentString);
            [self setPubTime:currentString];    
}
```

Then in:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ItemsCell";

    //ItemsViewCell Is class of UITableViewCell having the IBOutlet pubTimeLabel
    ItemsViewCell *cell = (ItemsViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];     

    TheItem *item = [[channel items] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    cell.pubTimeLabel.text = [item pubTime];

//    NSLog(@"PUB PUB %@", item.pubTime);


      return cell;
}
```

The NSLogs are showing the date string but its not showing in the tableviewcell. It was working fine on the iOS 6 but eversince i have updated it to iOS 7, the label which is supposed to show the date string in the tableviewcell is showing nothing. Tried asking the same question in iOS Dev Forum and based on the answer i received, its not an iOS 7 update problem.

Can anyone point out what is wrong? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** I have installed iOS 7 GM on my device, and then from the App Store i have installed one of my app that was submitted using the same project and boom that date label IS NOT getting displayed in it.

**UPDATE:** Here are the few things i have done to troubleshoot: Used NSLogs to see if at any point its nil which it isn't, changed the tableviewcell height, created a new label, creating a new outlet, removed the backgrounds and cell images, changed the font and color of the label, tried the project in both simulator and device BUT STILL no luck.

**UPDATE:** Ok based on the comments i have received, it looks like that i have some background or color issue or something like that. I have done some more troubleshooting and it has nothing to do with the color or background or any such thing. In the following code i have made some replacements:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
        //    [self setPubTime:currentString];  THIS LINE IS REPLACED WITH THE FOLLOWING

    NSDateFormatter *df1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df1 setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss ZZZZ"];
    NSDate *newDate = [df1 dateFromString:currentString];
    NSDateFormatter *df2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df2 setDateFormat:@"EEE,d MMM yyyy"];
    NSString *dateString = [df2 stringFromDate:newDate];
    NSLog(@"DATE STRING %@", dateString);
    [self setPubTime:dateString];
}
```

Now the same label is showing date that proves that there is no color or background issue with the label. The only issue why i am not using this updated code is that it is showing date in few cells and in few its not showing anything and retuning null.

Comment: Is pubTimeLabel a subclass of the cell's contentView? What are its backgroundColor and textColor values?

Comment: I bet your pubTimeLabel is nil in your "`cellForRowAtIndexPath:`" method.

Comment: @bneely  pubTimeLAbel is an Outlet inside ItemsViewCell which is a UITableViewCell class. I was earlier using the background image but removed it, its white now while the label is red. I have checked the colors and double checked and its not offscreen as well but still no luck

Comment: @MichaelDautermann tried logging pubTimeLabel and its showing the date in NSLog but not in the label

Comment: Set the label's text property to something else (i.e. a short string) and check that displays correctly.

Comment: Look at the @property statement for the label and make sure the little circle to the left has a dot in it.

Comment: Why is your method not returning a cell? And why are you casting the return from dequeReusableCell...?

Comment: @Abizern Its is returning the cell, i just updated in the question.

Comment: @HotLicks yes that dot circle is there. I have tried creating the IBOutlet again but it didn't work.

Comment: hmmm. What else have you left out?

Comment: @Abizern i have removed the code of other labels from the question that are implemented the same way but they are properly showing. In iOS 6 everything was working fine, but as soon as it was updated to GM, the date string label is missing, even the live app on the App Store is showing label for iOS 6 but not showing the label for iOS 7. What shall i do?

Comment: Can you see the label at all?  If you put fixed text in it with IB does that show?  (And are you sure you actually retrieved a cell and are not operating on a nil pointer?)

Comment: @HotLicks i am even logging cell.pubTimeLabel.text and the date string is appearing in the log. I cannot see the label at all when the program is run.

Comment: I would wonder if the label has gotten behind another component or has "fallen off the screen".  Log it's position and the size of it's parent view and see if the values make sense.  Also check that it's not hidden and that it's Z position is not placing it behind something else (that last one is tricky).  And try changing its background color.

Comment: @HotLicks Kindly see another update.

Comment: I'm sorry, your latest update doesn't make sense.  It looks like you're not even displaying the date in a cell.  (But then you say it shows in some cells but not others.  And what is "returning null"?)

Comment: @HotLicks Sorry for the confusion. Let me explain it. Actually, the program is parsing data from an rss feed. So there are 10 entries on each page which are wordpress posts. So it parses 10 posts and shows them in the tableview cells. So few entries are returning null and thats what not getting displayed in the tableview while few are properly showing the date in the log as well in the tableview. The feed has date in all 10 posts ofcourse. Let me know if it needs more explanation.

Comment: So is it partially working now? The label is working? Now the question is why are some dates nil?

Comment: @JustinAmberson yes with the latest update, its clear that there is nothing wrong with the label. Yes, its partially working but with some null values.

Comment: and on iOS6 all dates are displayed correctly? If this is the case then the parse workflow is changing somehow in iOS7. (FWIW I prefer to use parsing libraries instead of rolling my own)

Comment: @JustinAmberson With iOS 6, it was working fine without the nsdateformatter added in the last update. With NSDateFormatter, the last update, it shows partial results with both iOS 6 and iOS 7, so its safe to assume there is some other issue.

Comment: This smells like an ARC-related issue.

Comment: @HotLicks i think that Xcode handles ARC after the release of iOS 5. Anyways, how can i fix it?

Comment: ARC just "guarantees" that objects will be appropriately deleted in correctly written code -- it does not guarantee *when*.  And thus in INcorrectly written code it could release objects too soon.

Comment: @HotLicks i have seen few questions like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673302/nsdateformatter-returns-null-for-specific-dates that suggests using NSLocale but they didn't work for me as well. So this means it has no solution?

Comment: I see you got an answer in your other question -- it's failing on 24-hour time values since you're parsing with "hh".

Comment: I just had a very similar problem in iOS 7, and while looking for clues I came upon this question. FWIW, I'll relate what happened. My table view has static cells, and one of them wasn't updating with a relative time string I formatted. Normal text showed up right away, but a formatted date (which was just an NSString at this point) didn't. I could even read the text back from the detailTextLabel of the cell, but it wouldn't show. When I flicked the table view up and down, the text suddenly appeared in the cell. But I can't figure out what is special here. Doesn't occur on iOS 6.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is failing at the hh and you have to use HH in your date formatter in order for it to work.

Just use the 24(HH) or 12(hh) hour notation:

```
NSDateFormatter *df1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
df1.locale = locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"EN"];
[df1 setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZ"];
NSDate *newDate = [df1 dateFromString:currentString];
NSLog(@"NEW DATE %@", newDate);
```

Hope it helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know that dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier is supposed to create new prototype cells on it's own, but there may be some possibility that something that use to always work in iOS6 is now broken on iOS7. Try adding an alloc-init block in your method:

EDIT: Sorry didn't see all the comments, didn't realize you had the cell returning already.

Other than this you need to break in your cell returning code and make sure that the cell and the label are both non-nil. Did you try setting the label to @"Hello World" by chance?

Comment: The cell and label are not nil. I am even logging cell.pubTimeLabel.text and the date is appearing in the logs

Comment: What are the chances that there is another view on top of the pubTimeLabel, obscuring it?

Comment: not even negligible. Zero. I have created a whole new label, created an Outlet and everything but no chance. Also tried changing the height of the tablviewcell just to be sure but didn't work. On an iOS 6 device, the label is present when i downloaded the app from the App Store. On an iOS 7 GM device, i downloaded the app from the App Store and the label is NOT displaying.

Comment: It's got to be something so minor...can you verify that the pubTimeLabel's textColor is set to something not transparent? One of the comments above you say that you changed the background to be red. Explicitly change the textColor to [UIColor blackColor] in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Change it explicitly, in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Last thought after reading your update: You're getting NULL in some labels? This could be a race condition, you have an NSXMLParser doing some work in TheItem.m. What if you're trying to display this info before the XML parsing is finished?