# NSDateFormatter returns nil for specific date only in certain time zones

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents, nstimezone

Given this code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
NSArray *datesArray = @[@"20130326", @"20130327", @"20130328", @"20130329", @"20130330", @"20130331", @"20130401"];
for (NSString *dateString in datesArray) {
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    NSLog(@"date: %@", date);
}
```

This is the output in my timezone (EST):

```
date: 2013-03-26 04:00:00 +0000
date: 2013-03-27 04:00:00 +0000
date: 2013-03-28 04:00:00 +0000
date: 2013-03-29 04:00:00 +0000
date: 2013-03-30 04:00:00 +0000
date: 2013-03-31 04:00:00 +0000
date: 2013-04-01 04:00:00 +0000
```

When I go to Settings -> General -> Date & Time, and set the timezone to Amman, Jordan (GMT+3), this is the output for the same code:

```
date: 2013-03-25 22:00:00 +0000
date: 2013-03-26 22:00:00 +0000
date: 2013-03-27 22:00:00 +0000
date: (null)
date: 2013-03-29 21:00:00 +0000
date: 2013-03-30 21:00:00 +0000
date: 2013-03-31 21:00:00 +0000
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know for sure, but it is probably not a coincidence that the clocks change in Amman, Jordan on the 28th: http://www.evi.com/q/when_do_the_clocks_change_in_amman_jordan

My suspicion is that the clocks jump from 2013-03-28 21:59:59 to 2013-03-28 23:00:00, so the time 2013-03-28 22:00:00 doesn't exist in the Amman, Jordan time zone.

Comment: You were correct with this assumption, but even after normalizing the time there are still dates in Amman, Jordan that cause NSDateFormatter to return nil. Very, very strange. So far, I've only seen it in this time zone.

Answer (score 1):

I ran a loop over the years, months and days from 1970 till now, at dates DST started in Amman, `nil` was returned.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to specify the timezone for the `dateFormatter` when you set the value from string. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258266/nsdateformatter-datefromstring-returns-nil), its not exactly the same issue but it could help.

hope this helps